# Snaps don't launch after fixing issue with them not appearing in launcher

Tags: kubuntu, kde, launcher, snap, zsh

I'm having an issue where my Snap apps are not launching whenever I click on them.

The first issue was that they weren't showing up in the launcher, but I did some digging and it seems it was related to me installing ZSH, so I added `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'` to my `/etc/zsh/zprofile`.
This fixed the issue of them not showing up, but now they won't launch.

If I try to run something like `firefox` when it's installed through snap I get the error message:

```
cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory
```

These are some of the other commands I ran that I saw online, but they didn't help.

```bash
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/environment.d                                                                               
$ echo "PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin\nXDG_DATA_DIRS=\"${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share}:/var/lib/snapd/desktop\"" > ~/.config/environment.d/60-snap-icons-and-bin.conf
$ sudo ln -s /snap/bin/foo /usr/bin/foosnap                                                                     
$ sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications ~/.local/share/applications/snap
```

System Info:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04  
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4  
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0  
Qt Version: 5.15.8  
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-20-generic (64-bit)
```

Comment: What is the terminal output when you launch a snap app from terminal? E.g. `firefox` ?

Comment: I tried to run `firefox` and it says `cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory`, but it is installed. When I run another command like `prospect-mail` it says `cannot locate base snap core18: No such file or directory`, but that too is already installed.